# What does 'Logging' do in Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm struggling to work out what the `Logging` tag does in the **Dockerrun.aws.json** file for a **Single Container Docker Configuration**. All the [official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) say about it is `Logging – Maps the log directory inside the container.`

This sounds like they essentially create a volume from `/var/log` on the EC2 instance to a directory in the docker filesystem as specified by `Logging`. I have the following Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    ...
    "Logging": "/var/log/supervisor"
}
```

However, when I go to the AWS Console and request the logs for my instance, none of my custom log files located in `/var/log/supervisor` are in the log bundles. Can anyone explain to me what the purpose of this `Logging` tag is and how I may use it (or not) to retrieve my custom logs.

**EDIT**

Here are the Volume mappings for my container (didn't think to check that):

```
"Volumes": {
    "/var/cache/nginx": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/ff6ecc190ba3413660a946c557f14a104f26d33ecd13a1a08d079a91d2b5158e",
    "/var/log/supervisor": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/var/cache/nginx": true,
    "/var/log/supervisor": true
}
```

It turns out that `/var/log/supervisor` is mapping to `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app` rather than `/var/log` as I originally suspected. It'd be nice if this was clearer in the documentation.

But it also turns out that I was running the wrong Docker Image which explains why my log files weren't appearing anywhere! Doh!

Comment: Two things - 1) Can you verify that your log directory is correctly mapped on the EC2 instance? 2) Can you try downloading bundle logs following the guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html "Downloading Bundle Logs from the Elastic Beanstalk Console". Basically you request "Full logs" instead of "Last 100 lines".

Comment: @RohitBanga I edited my question. Didn't think to check my mappings which helped me debug the issue. If you want to answer with an explanation on how to check mappings or anything you think might help others vaguely relating to this then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Have you find any solution? I had the same problem with logs from `supervisord`

Comment: @hsrv my problem is answered in my edit. Whatever path you have in Logging will be mapped to the /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app directory when you download the logs from Amazon. If that doesn't fix it for you, ask your own question and hopefully someone can help. If you do ask, post the link here and I'll try answer it myself.

Comment: @StuartRobertson: I have the same issue and couldn't find a solution. I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418225/aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-single-container-docker-logging-parameter-in-dockerf